# .lower() and a regular expression in the same line?

Tags: python, regex, lowercase

I have a regular expression that eliminates all non-alpha characters

```
def genLetters(string):
  regex = re.compile('[^a-zA-Z]')
  newString = regex.sub("", string)
```

If I want to make this string lowercase, I have to define a new string (since they are immutable) like
`lowerString = newString.lower()`
It seems dumb to me that I would have to make a second string just to do the to lower, but if I remove the `A-Z` from the regex, I lose any characters that are uppercase which I don't want. I just want a final product of everything lower case.

Can this be done without the `lowerString`, or even cooler, can it be done in one line?

Comment: Wait, what's wrong with `newString = regex.sub("", string).lower()`?

Comment: Absolutely nothing, this is what I was looking for. I didn't know that was valid syntax to have something like .thisthing().thatThing(). New to python, but I like that a ton :)

Comment: For any returned value, you can act on it with a subsequent function. `something().dosomethingwiththatthing().again().etc()`

Comment: What about just using `print(''.join(c for c in s if c.isalpha()).lower())`? No need for regex here

Comment: And it does them in the order you call them? So the regex is completed first, and then the post regex'd value is called by the lower? @JacoblRR

Comment: as long as whatever is returned by `thisthing()` has a `thatThing` method, then you're set.

Comment: @ctwheels perhaps not, but I'm trying to figure out regular expressions and generator expressions, so I'm using them in little test cases.

Comment: @ctwheels yeaaa but that's going to be slow. Maybe it won't matter. But it pushes the iteration over the string into the Python interpreter level, which has way more overhead. If you can do your looping with regex or built-in string methods, it's almost always preferable.

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga using [regex method](https://tio.run/##HczJDoIwEADQO18x4kLrQlRcDyZ69Bc0krCMQkI7zbSk4s@j8f7yTOcq0knf18oQO2AMLJwgvIJncggZ5K0uKqAneOLSQoWM4GtXgW5VjmxhtU42293@cFxCpkuwncqpsTA4D0fjdDIVMgwYX/j@tYxxQcrUDYronmaLz2Vxe8wiGRiutRN/Fts2F1E0ByvjhjyykLLvvw) and using [string functions method](https://tio.run/##DcbLDoIwEAXQvV9xxQfFBVHxuTBx60@YlFrSGpgh05KGr6@e1Rnn6JianAMeKF5IwtFCo53IOHCHxPIJcFYsko8ONA2tlYDDsTmdL9fbfQ9NH4R5aLkPWD5X6817u1NVsRjFU1RlWX/ZkzLoWGDgCQG@g6l90P3otKqquudk5Z@cfw)

Comment: @ctwheels sorry, what is the conflict?

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga sorry not conflicting, more so just comparing the results, edited comment. Obviously it's a small use-case but both perform relatively similar

Comment: @Podo in Python attribute access (`.`) and call (`()`) syntax are basically binary operators. You can treat them the same way you treat `+` and `*` – as parts of an expression. And expressions are reduced in the order of operator precedence. Function call has the same precedence as attribute access. Thus you can rewrite `object().attribute()` as `(call (get attribute (call object)))`

Comment: @ctwheels that's the total time to run the entire process, including starting up the python interpreter, byte-code compilation, etc. Even then, the actual string-ops you are doing are probably being dwarfed by the amount of time required for I/O (i.e., the `print`).

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga very true, thanks for the info :)

Comment: @ctwheels so, to do timings, use the `timeit` module. `import timeit` then use `setup = "s = 'I wrote a bunch of words here with numbers 1234567890 and symbols !@#$%^&*()'; import re"`, now try: `timeit.timeit("''.join(c for c in s if c.isalpha()).lower()", setup)` and `timeit.timeit("regex = re.compile(r'[^a-zA-Z]'); regex.sub('', s).lower()", setup)`. I get 8.5 seconds vs 7.1 seconds (note, timeit repeats the code like, 100,000 times by default).

Comment: And note, that includes the regex compilation in the actual timing, if you move that to the setup: `timeit.timeit("regex.sub('', s).lower()", setup+"; regex = re.compile(r'[^a-zA-Z]')")` I get 6.5 seconds

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
newString = regex.sub("", string).lower()
```

Try to think of "functions returning" as "replacing the function call with the return value of the function". For example in the above case, `regex.sub` is evaluated first, and you should imagine that that call is replaced by the return value:

```
newString = "some String after substitution".lower()
```

This means that you can do everything you can do to a string on the return value of `regex.sub`. You can also call methods on the return value of `lower()`.

This also means that you can do your whole function in one line!

```
newString = re.compile('[^a-zA-Z]').sub("", string).lower()
```

Although this might be less readable.

By the way, the standard naming convention in python is not camel case but with underscores, so `newString` should be `new_string`.

Comment: Great explanation  of how this actually works. Thank you for taking the time, I'm sure others will find this helpful as well. As for the function in one line, I've discovered that many people like to write them, but as a new learner I find them so confusing to try and read. Also didn't know about the underscores, only ever dabbled in c++ and see lots of camel. Great Answer! (2min till except)

Comment: For this case, the `compile` step isn't getting you anything; you can just do `re.sub('[^a-zA-Z]', "", string).lower()`. And you can condense it even a bit more to `re.sub('[^a-z]', "", string.lower())`.

Comment: @Podo just remember, Python use *snake_case*.